# Можно ли сделать колонку как Алиса на питоне?

Tags: python, электроника, схемотехника

Вообщем у меня есть голосовой ассистент написанный на Python. И есть ли какая-нибудь возможность сделать из него колонку, может через какой-нибудь контролёр по типу ардуино?

Comment: Ардуино не потянет, нужен одноплатный компьютер типа RaspberryPi

Comment: Какая-то возможность есть.